# Multiple pages under single directory redirection to a single Page

Tags: redirects, mod-rewrite, apache2, 302-redirect

I have the following scenarios for web page redirects

1) All pages under `www.oldexamplesite.com/page/product/New-Design/*`  and All pages under `www.oldexamplesite.com/page/product/nature-of-design-purchase/*`

should be redirected to `https://www.testexamplesite.com/subjects/book/business-studies/`

2) Pages like `http://www.oldexamplesite.com/engine.jsp` and 
`http://www.oldexamplesite.com/engine.jsp?page=catalogues&portal=books` should be redirected to `https://www.testexamplesite.com` . There are multiple pages with `http://www.oldexamplesite.com/engine.jsp?*` which should be redirected to `https://www.testexamplesite.com`

3) All pages under `www.oldexamplesite.com/page/product/Old-Design/*`  and All pages under `www.oldexamplesite.com/page/product/nature-of-olddesign-purchase/*`

should be redirected to `https://www.testexamplesite.com/subjects/book/business-oldstudies/` .

To implement the above scenarios I tried the following redirect rules

```
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/page/product/New-Design/* [NC,OR]
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/page/product/nature-of-design-purchase/* [NC,OR]
   RewriteRule ^/.*$ https://www.testexamplesite.com/subjects/book/business-studies/ [R=302,L]

   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/engine.jsp* [NC]
   RewriteRule ^/.*$ https://www.testexamplesite.com/subjects/book/business-studies/ [R=302,L]

   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/page/product/Old-Design/* [NC,OR]
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/page/product/nature-of-olddesign-purchase/* [NC,OR]
   RewriteRule ^/.*$ https://www.testexamplesite.com/subjects/book/business-oldstudies/ [R=302,L]
```

With the above rules the redirections are not happening. So, please suggest how to make the redirections work .

Update:

Point 2)  Pages like `http://www.oldexamplesite.com/engine.jsp?page=fruits&portal=apples` and 
`http://www.oldexamplesite.com/engine.jsp?page=catalogues&portal=books` should be redirected to `https://www.testexamplesite.com` . Besides above two there are multiple jsp pages starting with `http://www.oldexamplesite.com/engine.jsp?........` which should be redirected to `https://www.testexamplesite.com` but there should but no redirection for `http://www.oldexamplesite.com/engine.jsp`

Comment: Do `oldexamplesite.com` and `testexamplesite.com` point to different filesystems?

Comment: The documentroot for both the URLs are on the same file system but different directories

Comment: Ok, but not a subdirectory of the other?

Comment: No.. It is like `/data/web/oldsite`  for the first URL and `/data/web/testsite` for the second URL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are close, but there are some errors:

> ```
> RewriteRule ^/.*$ ....
> ```

In `.htaccess`, the URL-path matched by the `RewriteRule` *pattern* does not start with a slash, so this should be simply `^.*$` (or even just `.*` - since regex is greedy by default), not `^/.*$`. By including the slash prefix, it will never match, so the directive does nothing. (You would need the slash prefix in a *server* or *virtualhost* context.)

> ```
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/page/product/New-Design/* [NC,OR]
> ```

The *CondPattern* (2nd argument to the `RewriteCond` directive) is a regex. The trailing `*` looks like you are treating like a *wildcard* expression. The `*` at the end matches the previous character 0 or more times, so in this case it is matching a slash 0 or more times - so again, this is not going to match the URLs you want to redirect. You should either use `.*` (to match 0 or more of any character: the *dot*), or omit it entirely, since you only need to match URLs that start with that URL-path.

> ```
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/page/product/New-Design/* [NC,OR]
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/page/product/nature-of-design-purchase/* [NC,OR]
> RewriteRule ^/.*$ https://www.testexamplesite.com/subjects/book/business-studies/ [R=302,L]
> ```

You should never include the `OR` flag on the last condition. This is essentially saying `OR true` and the rule will execute *unconditionally*  (that is, if the `RewriteRule` *pattern* matched).

> ```
>  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/engine.jsp* [NC]
>  RewriteRule ^/.*$ https://www.testexamplesite.com/subjects/book/business-studies/ [R=302,L]
> ```

The `REQUEST_URI` server variable does not contain the query string, so if you want to match *any* query string then you don't need to do anything in this respect, you just need to match the required URL-path. (To specifically match the query string you need a condition that checks against the `QUERY_STRING` server variable.)

Also, where possible it is more efficient to perform the necessary URL-path checks in the `RewriteRule` *pattern*, rather than using an additional `RewriteCond` (condition) directive. So, the above could be rewritten as a single directive:

```
 RewriteRule ^engine\.jsp$ https://www.testexamplesite.com/subjects/book/business-studies/ [R=302,L]
```

Remember to escape literal dots in the regex. You did state in your question that this should redirect to `https://www.testexamplesite.com`, not `https://www.testexamplesite.com/subjects/book/business-studies/`, as you've stated here?

---

#### In Summary

So, bringing this together, try the following instead. Note that these directives need to go *before* the WordPress front-controller, at the top of the `.htaccess` file.

```
RewriteRule ^page/product/(new-design|nature-of-design-purchase)/ https://www.testexamplesite.com/subjects/book/business-studies/ [NC,R=302,L]

RewriteRule ^engine\.jsp$ https://www.testexamplesite.com/ [NC,R=302,L]

RewriteRule ^page/product/(old-design|nature-of-olddesign-purchase)/ https://www.testexamplesite.com/subjects/book/business-oldstudies/ [R=302,L]
```

Note that I removed the end-of-string anchor (`$`) from the `RewriteRule` *pattern*. And changed the *pattern* to lowercase, since you have the `NC` (`nocase`) flag anyway.

**UPDATE#1:** To redirect only when a query string is present on the `/engine.jsp` URL you’ll need to add a condition to the middle rule that checks against the `QUERY_STRING` server variable. For example:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} .
RewriteRule ^engine\.jsp$ https://www.testexamplesite.com/ [NC,QSD,R=302,L]
```

The regex (a single dot) in the *CondPattern* ensures that the query string is present on the request.

The QSD flag (Apache 2.4+) is required to discard the query string from the redirected response.

---

> **UPDATE#2:** Sorry , If I have missed to add earlier, for this requirement we are using Virtualhosts directive and not .htaccess

In that case you will need to match a slash prefix on the URL-path in the `RewriteRule` *pattern*. This is because in a virtualhost (or server) context, the `RewriteRule` directive matches against the full URL-path, not a *relative* URL-path (that is *relative* to the directory of where the `.htaccess` file is contained).

So, finally we have:

```
RewriteRule ^/page/product/(new-design|nature-of-design-purchase)/ https://www.testexamplesite.com/subjects/book/business-studies/ [NC,R=302,L]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} .
RewriteRule ^/engine\.jsp$ https://www.testexamplesite.com/ [NC,QSD,R=302,L]

RewriteRule ^/page/product/(old-design|nature-of-olddesign-purchase)/ https://www.testexamplesite.com/subjects/book/business-oldstudies/ [R=302,L]
```

NB: These directives can be made to work in both contexts (ie. *server* and *directory*) by making the slash prefix in the `RewriteRule` *pattern* optional. eg. `^/?engine\.jsp$`.

Comment: I have updated point 2) as there is some change in our requirement but rest are working perfect

Comment: Will this work for point 2) requirement `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^ ^/engine\.jsp$
RewriteRule ^/engine\.jsp\(.*) https://www.testexamplesite.com/ [NC,R=302,L]`

Comment: That code doesn’t look valid. If I understand your requirement then you need an additional condition that checks against the QUERY_STRING server variable. I’ve updated my answer.

Comment: Thanks again . It works if I prefix ^engine\.jsp$ with `backslash(/)` . But one issue is there it is adding the `QUERY_STRING` to the redirected URL i.e like `https://www.testexamplesite.com/QUERY_STRING`

Comment: If I just type `http://www.oldexamplesite.com/engine.jsp` it is working fine and there is no redirection

Comment: Actually it just adds the query string to the redrected URL in browser `https://www.testexamplesite.com/QUERY_STRING` but it is opening `https://www.testexamplesite.com` as per the requirement which is fine

Comment: Ah, sorry, you need the QSD flag to discard the query string (assuming you are on Apache 2.4) from the redirection response. I assume you are using .htaccess? In which case you should not prefix the RewriteRule pattern with a slash.

Comment: Perfect!. Thanks so much. Sorry , If  I have missed to add earlier, for this requirement we are using `Virtualhosts` directive and not .htaccess.

Comment: If these directives are directly in a VirtualHost context (and not in a `<Directory>` container) then you will need to match a slash prefix on the URL-path.